# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 freezes every few hours

Tags: gnome, graphics, amd-graphics, crash, 17.04

I recently installed Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 x64 with a bootable USB (using rufus).
My laptop is a Dell Insprion 15 5000, i7 up to 3.1 Ghz and a AMD Radeon GPU.

Right after the installation, I had some problems like the whole system freezing after I logged in. Thankfully I fixed this problem by editing one file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.modeset=0 amdgpu.runpm=0"
```

The problem was solved, everything was working fine until one day when Ubuntu all of a sudden crashed while I was watching a video. I didn't think much about it and restarted, but a few hours later it crashed again.

It looks like this might have something to do with the AMD Radeon GPU again.
I checked other posts and website and they said to add something else on GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT but I don't know if that will fix the problem or will the previous problem of Ubuntu crashing after login come back.

I also found out that the laptop was getting quite hot. Approx ~10-20 before a crash, I checked the max temperature and it was 78 degree C. So i'm not sure if it could be overheating issues.

Some help would be  appreciated :)
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
superpykkon@superpykkon ~/Desktop> dpkg -l intel-microcode
dpkg-query: no packages found matching intel-microcode
superpykkon@superpykkon ~/Desktop> dpkg -l thermald
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-====================================================================
ii  thermald                        1.5.4-4ubuntu1       amd64                Thermal monitoring and controlling daemon
superpykkon@superpykkon ~/Desktop> free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G        1.7G        1.1G         36M        997M        1.8G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
superpykkon@superpykkon ~/Desktop>
```

**EDIT #2:**

```
superpykkon@superpykkon:~$ cat /etc/crypt*
cat: '/etc/crypt*': No such file or directory
superpykkon@superpykkon:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1c608749-0ff4-4c10-abf4-323c481a7936 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5003-97BA  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
superpykkon@superpykkon:~$
```

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l intel-microcode` and `dpkg -l thermald` and `free -h`. Edit your question with that info... not in the comments please. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: There you go, @heynnema  Oh and, I recently added "nomodeset" to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, I'm currently testing if that solved the problem or not. So far, I've encountered no system crashes .

Comment: I would check to make sure that you have the latest BIOS for your machine by going to the manufacturer's web site. I'd install `intel-microcode` to make sure that your processors were running the latest microcode. If that didn't fix it, I'd look into writing a custom `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` tailored to your configuration. See `man thermald` and `man thermal-conf.xml`. More on that later.

Comment: Hello @heynnema, I think the  problem is fixed. After adding "nomodeset" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, my laptop isn't crashing anymore :D.

Comment: I really don't think that's a permanent fix. With nomodeset you can't set the video display to optimal settings in the System Settings. It just may point to a video driver issue which might be solved with a newer version of the driver. I'd still do the `intel-microcode` and work the temp issue with `thermald`... as you still have problems there. Did you check the BIOS? I recommended all of these things for a reason.

Comment: Alright, I installed `intel-microcode`, and also checked with the BIOS. The current BIOS version on my laptop is `1.1.5`, on the website, there is an update to `1.2.8` but it's all windows executables ;( `http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-14-5459-laptop/drivers?os=biosa`. Will I be able to run this using wine?

Comment: Ah @heynnema, I forgot to mention that my laptop has an AMD Radeon R5 M335 4GB DDR3L GPU. Can you please tell me where I can get the proper drivers for it? Maybe that will fix the problem.

Comment: No, you can't use Wine (for anything). This is why I tell users not to remove Windows... they'll need it for BIOS updates,etc. You'll have to install Windows somewhere, even if it's on an external disk, to install the BIOS update. I think that's important. I couldn't look at the docs for the BIOS update because the link that you left doesn't work. I did some brief research on the AMD drivers, and you may have a problem there. I'd start a new question for that.

Comment: To be honest, the only reason I switched from Windows to Ubuntu is because of the constant BSOD(s). It got so bad that every time I'd get a BSOD after the booting screen with some random error code, I couldn't even login. The first time this happened, I had to get the laptop repaired and certain hardware replaced to get it working, but, when it happened again, I quickly changed to Ubuntu to prevent anymore damage. For the BIOS update, will a temporary dual boot work? [working link](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-14-5459-laptop/drivers?os=biosa)

Comment: Yes, a temporary dual-boot would work fine.

Comment: I think I know what your problem might be. Show me the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/crypt*`.

Comment: Alrighty, @heynnema, edited with output. Oh and by the way, I remember doing a "memtester" before asking this question. I remember that my laptop became so darn slow, like a 0.1FPS game :P but the mouse was moving around (after a couple seconds). But then I think it became unresponsive after a few minutes and I did a forced shutdown. Well that ended up messing up the filesystem, and ubuntu wasn't able to boot. After doing `fsck /dev/sda2`, everything was working fine. I think this happened while I was still experiencing constant "freezes".~

Comment: Well oh darn. I thought for sure that I knew what was causing your freezing... it had to do with 17.04 and encrypted /swapfiles... but you don't have that. Now I'm all out of ideas for you. Sorry.

Comment: It's ok, I'll somehow find a way ;-;

Comment: Keep me posted, if you can. Inquiring minds would like to know.

Comment: @heynnema  I found some answers saying to install a "new" kernel.. Umm, yeah, I have no clue, [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55342). Since it **is** a "full freeze" because I can't even SSH into it when it happens. So yeah, and many others are saying to install drivers for the gpu but in my case, that's impossible. Oh and `lspci` shows some extra info about the GPU `01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] (rev 81)`

Comment: I'm sure that you've probably checked http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux

Comment: You might look at `ukuu` in the repositories. It might make installing a newer kernel easier.

Comment: Hey  @heynnema, I think I fixed it! I swapped the RAM to a different slot and so far it hasn't crashed! Maybe the connector was damaged.

Comment: But if that is the case (which by now I'm sure is) then that's kinda sad because I wanted to add a new 4GB RAM from another laptop which I don't use anymore. But if the socket is damaged thennnn I can't ;^;

Comment: Maybe, but didn't you run memtest as per our previous discussion? There could have just been some dirt in the RAM socket. It happens. Make sure that you haven't disrupted memory interleaving by putting RAM into mismatched RAM sockets... of course, if this is a laptop, you may not have much choice.

Comment: Yep, I ran memtester after swapping. It all came out ok

Comment: @heynnema [everything I did](https://pastebin.com/mwtrKhbm)

Comment: Right, so, after I swapped the RAM to slot 2, I did a little test for a couple of hours, surprisingly, there were no crashes at all. Now after adding a new RAM to slot 1, if it freezes, then it definitely should be something to do with slot 1. Maybe damaged or dirty (I did blow on the socket and RAM a bunch of times :P). If no freezes occur, then it has nothing to do with Ubuntu, it's because of hardware (I guess) issues.

Comment: It may be a problem with that RAM slot, or having to do with the RAM size, or the RAM stick timing spec. To test RAM/slots, use a single RAM stick in one slot at a time, test, switch that same RAM stick to another slot, retest. Then repeat with the 2nd RAM stick by itself. I assume that you've got a 4G and a 2G, and only two slots, yes? If you have more than that, with all RAM inserted, do a `sudo dmidecode -t memory` and let me see.

Comment: @heynnema Actually, I have two 4G RAM and there's two slots, so I get 8G in total. But now after testing the laptop with both RAM (s) inserted, it didn't freeze at all. So maybe it was the old RAM on slot 1. Maybe it malfunctioned on slot 1 only.

Comment: [dmidecode](https://pastebin.com/f7NwB7FP)

Comment: Good. I'm glad it's working. So you actually replaced some RAM, yes?

Comment: @heynnema swapped and added a new ram stick. Btw I'm so very grateful for all the help and I really want to repay you for all the time and effort you put into helping me with this ;p. Oh and, you don't really need windows to do a BIOS upgrade, you can do it even if your computer is running a OS other than windows.
 [see here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN171755/updating-the-dell-bios-in-linux-and-ubuntu-environments?lang=EN)  --   [full doc](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN284433/what-is-bios-and-how-to-update-the-bios-on-your-dell-system?lang=EN).

Comment: You're very welcome. Nice to see that Dell has built the BIOS update right into their BIOS... no stink'in Windows required! I'll put together a **very** brief summary of what we did together, and you can "repay" me by voting/accepting it... fair enough? Give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Summary...

- we updated the Dell BIOS from 1.1.5 to 1.2.8
- we installed `intel-microcode`
- we ran the `memtest` memory diagnostic
- we replaced what must have been a faulty RAM stick, 'cause it's working now!
- and more I can't remember...